# SSRS date and scroll bar issues

Tags: ssrs-2012

Wondering if someone can advise on the following please:

In SSRS I have a date from and date to parameter - If I enter a date where the year is less than 30 it will prefix it with 20 I.E 01/01/19 and tab off will change it to 01/01/2019 but when we enter a date with a year of 30 or later it prefixes it with 19 so 01/01/30 changes to 01/01/1930.

As this report will always be in the 2000 - 2999 range they have requested that when you enter the year and tab off it always prefixes it with 20.  Is there a way to do this?

What and where is the default width and height of the SSRS portal? For some reason when this loads it has the scroll bars on the side and bottom. This doesn't look too great and also when a report loads that has scroll bars on the report the IE scroll bars hide them so you have to move those up and down to get to the report scroll bar if that makes sense? The users are hating this.

I understand I can manually zoom in and out to make the page fit, but that isn't a solution for everyone using these reports, they will become frustrated. They aren't being used on small monitors either so shouldn't need to load with a scroll bar on the actual screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's not an easy way to change the behavior of the date box. You could change your date parameter to a text field and handle the formatting when you use it. It wouldn't change when they type though.

```
WHERE D_DATE = CAST( CASE WHEN LEN(@DATE_PARAM) = 8 THEN LEFT(@DATE_PARAM, 6) + '20' + RIGHT(@DATE_PARAM, 2) ELSE @DATE_PARAM END
```

As far as the scroll bars, does your report have extra space in design mode? You can control that by grabbing the right or bottom edge and making it smaller or using the **Page Size** property of the report. There is also an **Interactive Size** property that may also be increasing the size of your report.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me.  I considered free text but this would mean the user having to enter the date and as we have international offices there would be date format errors no doubt and no validation should it become free text.  

Regarding the scroll bars.  I'm referring to the SSRS portal, so before you open any reports, when you log open the portal to browse for reports there re scroll bars on there, I want to remove these as these cover the valid scroll bars on a report